# Java PreparedStatement executeBatch method throws unique constraint for primary key

Tags: java, junit, fxml

I have written an addContacts method for my DatabaseUtilities class for use in my messenger app. The relevant database tables are **accounts**, **contacts** and **accountContact**. I added the latter in my attempt at 3NF. When running the code through the JUnit test harness found lower down I receive this error:

> failed to add contacts: [SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY]  A PRIMARY KEY constraint failed (UNIQUE constraint failed: accountContact.uid, accountContact.cid)

I have tried commenting out the code responsible for halting auto-commit out of the belief that having out of order commits might be the problem but this was not the issue. I am aware that this SQL works when used directly in the sqlite database with contacts being added first one by one and then accountContact records following.

The following code is my addContacts method:

```
  boolean addContacts(List<Contact> contacts, Account account) {
    try {
        try {
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);

            queryInsertContact.clearParameters();
            queryInsertAccountContact.clearParameters();

            for (Contact contact : contacts) {
                if (ipv4Pattern.matcher(contact.getIpv4()).matches() && contact.getAlias().length() <= 256 &&
                        contact.getTlsPort() >= 1024 && contact.getTlsPort() <= 65535) {
                    queryInsertContact.setString(1, contact.getCid());
                    queryInsertContact.setString(2, contact.getAlias());
                    queryInsertContact.setString(3, contact.getIpv4());
                    queryInsertContact.setInt(4, contact.getTlsPort());
                    queryInsertContact.addBatch();

                    queryInsertAccountContact.setInt(1, account.getUid());
                    queryInsertAccountContact.setString(2, contact.getCid());
                    queryInsertAccountContact.addBatch();
                } else {
                    throw new SQLException("Format incorrect");
                }
            }

            queryInsertContact.executeBatch();
            queryInsertAccountContact.executeBatch(); // THE TEST HARNESS FAILS HERE

            conn.commit();
            return true;

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println("failed to add contacts: " + e.getMessage());
            conn.rollback();
        } finally {
            conn.setAutoCommit(true);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
    }

    return false;
}
```

The following code is my addContacts test harness:

```
 @org.junit.Test
public void addContacts() {

    List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        byte[] salt = getSalt(), hashWithSalt = getKey(salt, "password");
        String stringSalt = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(salt);
        String tempHash = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hashWithSalt);

        Account account = new Account("james", tempHash, stringSalt, 100000);
        Contact contact = new Contact("abc", "accountboi", "127.0.0.1", 1025);
        databaseUtilities.addAccount(account, contact);

        try { // THIS CODE JUST GETS THE ACCOUNT INSTANCE WITH ITS UID DEFAULT WAS -1
            account = databaseUtilities.getAccount(account.getUsername());
        }catch (SQLException e){}

        contacts.add(new Contact("f1dg13d7f8sfd", "nrmad", "127.0.0.1", 1025));
    assertTrue(databaseUtilities.addContacts(contacts, account));

    contacts.clear();
    contacts.add(new Contact("f1dg13d7f8sfd", "nrmad", "127.0.0.1", 1025));
    assertFalse(databaseUtilities.addContacts(contacts, account));

    contacts.clear();
    contacts.add(new Contact("f1dg13d7f8sfd1", "nrmad", "1234-0-0-1", 1025));
    assertFalse(databaseUtilities.addContacts(contacts, account));

    contacts.clear();
    contacts.add(new Contact("f1dg13d7f8sfd2", "nrmad", "127-a-a-a", 1));
    assertFalse(databaseUtilities.addContacts(contacts, account));

    contacts.clear();
    contacts.add(new Contact("f1dg13d7f8sfd3", "nrmad", "127.0.0.0", 65536));
    assertFalse(databaseUtilities.addContacts(contacts, account));

    contacts.clear();
    contacts.add( new Contact("f1dg13d7f8sfd4", "nrmad", "127-a-a-a", -1));
    assertFalse(databaseUtilities.addContacts(contacts, account));

    // UP TO HERE EVERYTHING IS WORKING. THE FOLLOWING CODE IS WHERE THE ERROR IS THROWN        

    contacts.clear();
    contacts.add(new Contact("a1", "nrmad", "127.0.0.1", 1025));
    contacts.add(new Contact("a2", "nrmad", "127.0.0.1", 1025));
    contacts.add(new Contact("a3", "nrmad", "127.0.0.1", 1025));

    assertTrue(databaseUtilities.addContacts(contacts, account)); // THIS STATEMENT


    }catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException |InvalidKeySpecException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The following SQL statements are the dump of the **accounts**, **contacts** and **accountContact** tables respectively:

```
CREATE TABLE contacts(cid TEXT PRIMARY KEY, alias TEXT NOT NULL, ipv4 TEXT NOT NULL, tlsport INTEGER NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE accounts(uid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, username TEXT NOT NULL, pass TEXT NOT NULL, salt TEXT NOT NULL, iterations INTEGER NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE accountContact( uid INTEGER, cid TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(uid, cid), FOREIGN KEY (uid) REFERENCES accounts(uid),FOREIGN KEY (cid) REFERENCES contacts(cid));
```

These SQL statements are used to initialise the prepared statements used in the above code

```
private static final String INSERT_CONTACT = "INSERT INTO contacts(cid, alias, ipv4, tlsport) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
private static final String INSERT_ACCOUNT = "INSERT INTO accounts(uid, username, pass, salt, iterations) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
private static final String INSERT_ACCOUNTCONTACT = "INSERT INTO accountContact(uid, cid) VALUES(?,?)";
```

This has been confusing me for a while and any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was using the clearParameters() method of the PreparedStatement thinking it would reset the object after each test of the addContacts() method however there is a separate method which does this for batches clearBatch()